# Unable to resolve ip from hostname inside container

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

Im experimenting with Docker containers and Im having a problem with resolving ips from hostnames from inside my server. 
It works fine on my machine (windows 10).

Basically Im just pinging hostnames on our internal network from my server (windows server 2016 running in a VM on VMWare) and it cannot find the host.

I run the container like this:

```
docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver
```

and when in the command prompt I ping one of our internal servers using its hostname. 
This works fine on my windows 10 machine.

However if I ping the ip directly it works on the server.
If I ping the same hostname directly from the host it works fine.

Im quite new at this and I've been trying to figure it out using various guides, but I havent found anyone who has asked this before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The Docker container does not know anything about "your" network. Docker uses virtual interfaces to spin container - networks.

```
docker run --dns=127.0.0.1
```

Anyway, you can add your DNS Server to the Docker engine or add some static "host" entries like:

```
docker run --add-host=myserver.local:192.168.66.66 ...
```

Comment: I dont understand, what is the difference between the two machines. 
Why does it work on one and not the other?